# What are disadvantages if I use Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: 10.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is installing Ubuntu 10.10 still a viable option?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151409/is-installing-ubuntu-10-10-still-a-viable-option)

I tried to use the recent Ubuntu version on my laptop, but the performance wasn't that great. So I am now trying to use some older version such as ubuntu 10.10 on the machine and I know that's out of support. If so, what are the disadvantages that I may have? Maybe some security issues?

Thank you

Comment: I agree with K.K. and To Do. You don't want outdated software that isn't supported by third parties. You want to go with 12.04, possibly with a xfce/xubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you installed Ubuntu 12.04 because Canonical will support it with updates until April 2017. It is about half year long Since canonical Closed its support.

You will not get Security Updates and not able to Upgrade latest Software released after April 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 10.10 is no longer supported. No security updates will be issued.

What I suggest is using the latest version of [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/).

They are modern but use a less resource intensive window manager (xfce or lxde respectively)